# props from deep nested children components won't display unless I refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I'm building a react app, I use Redux to manage the state and react router v4 for routing. I use webpack as module bundler. And it has this structure.

```
-Wrapper
 -Home /
 -Homepage /h
    --GalleryContainer  /h/gallery
       ---Gallery  /h/gallery
       ---Item    /h/gallery/:itemId
    --About /h/about
    --Links /h/links
```

I'm at `Item` component, where I would render only the element that matches `itemId`. when I first click to display, it doesn't render unless I refresh and in some cases renders an error of module not found (for picture) but render if I refresh the page. The rendering works fine on other components, but not on this one where matching params is necessary for displaying the appropriate props.

Any input or help into the right direction would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'

 class Item extends React.Component {

  render() {

   const item=this.props.items[this.props.match.params.itemId]

    return (
      <div>
      <h1> {item.title} </h1>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Item
```

**Edit**: The props passed from connect component displays normally in `Item` component, like if I `console.log(this.props.items)` it displays after clicking. but once they're conditioned by custom params `const item=this.props.items[this.props.match.params.itemId]`, I get this problem.

Adding GalleryContainer routes

```
<div>
    <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}`} 
    exact render={(props)=><Gallery 
        gallery={this.props.gallery}  
        {...props}  />} />

    <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/:itemId`} 
    render={(props)=><Item 
        gallery={this.props.gallery}
        item={this.props.items} {...props} />} />

</div>
```

If there is another components to post to clarify this issue, let me know.

**Solution**
It finally worked. It turns out that I added a space in

> ```
> <Link to={`h/portfolio/${pod.code}`}>
> ```

which explains the error at rendering at first time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        import React from 'react'

        class Item extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state={item:null};
            } 

            componentWillMount() 
            {
                this.setState({item:this.props.items[this.props.match.params.itemId]});
            }

            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                this.setState({item:nextProps.items[nextProps.match.params.itemId]});
            }

        render() {
            let {item} = this.state;
            return (
            <div>
            <h1> item?item.title:""} </h1>
            </div>

            )
        }
        }

        export default Item
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. And I just tried it, still produces same issue but at first  throws error "cannot read property title of undefined", when i refresh, it works.

Comment: Edited my answer. Should fix the issue.

Comment: Still not working. Produces same issue. I'm looking at what exactly causes this issues and in react dev tools, I get in routes for `itemId` "node was deleted" it looks like the component is being unmounted after the click but created and rendered again after refresh...

Comment: I ran the above code, (after removing the home level) and it works as expected. Can you post the Homepage and Wrapper component too?

Comment: Thank you for replying and helping. The problem wasn't in components receiving props but was a typo mistakes at coding. Though your answer really helped in other areas of application. so i'll give it an upvote. :)

Comment: Great to know you found the cause of the problem :)